# MS Access summing a datediff expression column

Tags: ms-access

Using Access 2013 I have a calculated a column in a query that is the `datediff` from a clients intake date to `now()`, the formula is:

```
DateDiff("d",[table1]![intake_date],Now())
```

So the column will give the total number of days the client has been our client. This works great. Each client has a total number of days populated. Now what I want to do is add those numbers up to find the total number days from that column. What I can't figure out is how to get a sum of that column to populate in a textbox. I have a form with a textbox that I want to sum to show in. The formula I assumed would work is

```
=Sum([queryname]![columnname])
```

but that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
=Sum([columnname])
```

can only be used if `columnname` is a field in the form's RecordSource.
Typically in the footer of a continuous form.

To show the sum of a query that is independent of the form, use the [`DSum`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dsum.php) function:

```
=DSum("columnname", "queryname")
```

Comment: This is helpful! Thank you very much!